# Filter documents by sub strings in a field

Tags: haskell, rethinkdb

This is taken from API examples.

```
r.table('posts').filter(function(doc){
    return doc('message').match("Blah")
}).run(conn, callback)
```

How can I do exact simple thing with the Haskell driver?

Doing something like this

```
run' h' $ table "posts" # filter (\doc -> match "Blah" (doc ! "message"))
```

...does not make any sense as match returns ReQL, not Bool.
Any way to use match inside filter like the above JavaScript example?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like there is a function `run :: (Expr query, Result r) => RethinkDBHandle -> query -> IO r`, which can be instantiate with `Bool`. Alternatively, you can pattern match on the result of `run'` (`Datum`) which has a constructor `Bool  :: Bool -> Datum`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using `filter` from the Prelude.

You should be using `filter` from the `Database.RethinkDB` module. If you import the module qualified:

```
import qualified Database.RethinkDB as R
```

You can then use `R.filter`:

```
run' h' $ table "posts" # R.filter (\doc -> match "Blah" (doc ! "message"))
```